# run a procedure in while loop

Tags: sql, loops, plsql

I have this stored proc :

```
begin
Sp_Racf_Test;
end;
```

I don't want to edit anything inside this proc.
I want to run a loop statement where it should run the proc Sp_Racf_Test until
a column `RACF_ID` in table `tem_joins` is null. I mean the loop of running stored procedure should stop when there are no null values in the column `RACF_ID` of table `tem_joins`.

Please suggest a query

Comment: What should happen if there is a record in the table after the null value in the `RACF_ID` in table tem_joins . For example.. 1,2,,4

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
declare
    v_count number := 1;
    begin
    while v_count > 0 loop
      Select count(*) into v_count from tem_joins
    where racf_id is null;
    if v_count > 0 then
      Sp_Racf_Test;
    else
      exit;
    end if;
    end loop;
    end;
```